# Why do we need an infinitely differentiable function for writing Taylor series of it?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Today in our maths class we were discussing about Taylor series. Our professor pointed out that we require an infinitely differentiable function for writing Taylor series. But my question is that is it really practically necessary? I mean for an approximation in practical purposes we would write a polynomial till degree n where n is finite(more simply upto 6 or 7 degree) and take higher orders of x  as just 0.Will this type of real time approximation be very vague.Are there any real world applications where we need accuracy very high.Thanks!

Comment: You have to distinguish between the Taylor *series* and the Taylor *polynomial* of order $n$. Then you have that the Taylor theorem, which says that you can approximate a suitable function with a polynomial of degree $n$ (where approximate= there is a remainder), is true under the hypotesis of $f$, the suitable function, being (for example, but there are more general hypotesis) $n$ differentiable on your domain

Comment: ... simply because all $f^{(n)}(0)$ (or $f^{(n)}(x_0)$) occur in the very definition of the series.

Comment: Infinitely differentiable... the key question is **where**? As Hagen mentions it is required at the very center point for the definition to make sense. Other than that?